Unity WebSocket Vuforia Camera Feed Error in Python-Mediapipe Virtual Try-On Integration
I'm trying to create a virtual try-on application using Vuforia as the AR SDK with Unity. Since Vuforia doesn't support body tracking, I planned to set up a WebSocket connection between Unity and Python. My goal is to send the camera feed from Unity to Python, process it in Python with MediaPipe, and return key joint coordinates for body tracking.
I've successfully established a connection between Unity and Python, and I can send and receive data. However, when I attempt to send the Vuforia camera feed, I encounter an issue. Following the Vuforia documentation for "Working with the Camera in Unity," I tried accessing the camera image with this code :
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Vuforia;
using Image = Vuforia.Image;

public class CameraImageAccess : MonoBehaviour
{
    const PixelFormat PIXEL_FORMAT = PixelFormat.RGB888;
    const TextureFormat TEXTURE_FORMAT = TextureFormat.RGB24;

    public RawImage RawImage;

    Texture2D mTexture;
    bool mFormatRegistered;

    void Start()
    {
        // Register Vuforia Engine life-cycle callbacks:
        VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaStarted += OnVuforiaStarted;
        VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaStopped += OnVuforiaStopped;
        if (VuforiaBehaviour.Instance != null)
            VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.World.OnStateUpdated += OnVuforiaUpdated;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Unregister Vuforia Engine life-cycle callbacks:
        if (VuforiaBehaviour.Instance != null)
            VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.World.OnStateUpdated -= OnVuforiaUpdated;

        VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaStarted -= OnVuforiaStarted;
        VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaStopped -= OnVuforiaStopped;

        if (VuforiaApplication.Instance.IsRunning)
        {
            // If Vuforia Engine is still running, unregister the camera pixel format to avoid unnecessary overhead
            // Formats can only be registered and unregistered while Vuforia Engine is running
            UnregisterFormat();
        }

        if (mTexture != null)
            Destroy(mTexture);
    }

    /// 
    /// Called each time the Vuforia Engine is started
    /// 
    void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        mTexture = new Texture2D(0, 0, TEXTURE_FORMAT, false);
        // A format cannot be registered if Vuforia Engine is not running
        RegisterFormat();
    }

    /// 
    /// Called each time the Vuforia Engine is stopped
    /// 
    void OnVuforiaStopped()
    {
        // A format cannot be unregistered after OnVuforiaStopped
        UnregisterFormat();
        if (mTexture != null)
            Destroy(mTexture);
    }

    /// 
    /// Called each time the Vuforia Engine state is updated
    /// 
    void OnVuforiaUpdated()
    {
        var image = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.GetCameraImage(PIXEL_FORMAT);

        // There can be a delay of several frames until the camera image becomes available
        if (Image.IsNullOrEmpty(image))
            return;

        Debug.Log("\nImage Format: " + image.PixelFormat +
                  "\nImage Size: " + image.Width + " x " + image.Height +
                  "\nBuffer Size: " + image.BufferWidth + " x " + image.BufferHeight +
                  "\nImage Stride: " + image.Stride + "\n");

        // Override the current texture by copying into it the camera image flipped on the Y axis
        // The texture is resized to match the camera image size
        image.CopyToTexture(mTexture, true);

        RawImage.texture = mTexture;
        RawImage.material.mainTexture = mTexture;
    }

    /// 
    /// Register the camera pixel format
    /// 
    void RegisterFormat()
    {
        // Vuforia Engine has started, now register camera image format
        var success = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFrameFormat(PIXEL_FORMAT, true);
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully registered pixel format " + PIXEL_FORMAT);
            mFormatRegistered = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to register pixel format " + PIXEL_FORMAT +
                           "\n the format may be unsupported by your device;" +
                           "\n consider using a different pixel format.");
            mFormatRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    /// 
    /// Unregister the camera pixel format
    /// 
    void UnregisterFormat()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unregistering camera pixel format " + PIXEL_FORMAT);
        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFrameFormat(PIXEL_FORMAT, false);
        mFormatRegistered = false;
    }
}

I’m executing the code above by attaching the CameraImageAccess script to the Vuforia ARCamera in my Unity scene. When I run Play Mode in Unity, Vuforia initializes, and this script begins running. This setup should allow me to access and process the camera feed from the Vuforia ARCamera but I keep getting stuck at this log error:
ConfigureVideoBackground
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.UnityLogger:LogInfo (string)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.Log:Info (string)
Vuforia.MonoCameraConfiguration:ConfigureVideoBackground (UnityEngine.Matrix4x4)
Vuforia.MonoCameraConfiguration:CheckForSurfaceChanges (UnityEngine.Matrix4x4)
Vuforia.CameraController:UpdateCamera (UnityEngine.Matrix4x4)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.StateProcessor:ProcessState (Vuforia.IVuState,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<int, Vuforia.Internal.Observers.IObserver>,Vuforia.Internal.Rendering.IVideoBackgroundRenderer,Vuforia.Internal.Rendering.IVBAugmentationRenderer,Vuforia.ICameraController,Vuforia.Internal.Core.IWorldOriginProvider,Vuforia.Internal.Observers.DeviceObserver)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:UpdateState ()
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:OnUnityUpdate ()
System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke (object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling (System.Action)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.UnityLifeCycleListener:Update ()

When I see "Successfully registered pixel format" in the RegisterFormat() function, it confirms that the camera format registration worked and that Vuforia supports PixelFormat.RGB888.
In OnVuforiaUpdated()function, I look for logs like:
Image Format: {image.PixelFormat}
Image Size: {image.Width} x {image.Height}
Buffer Size: {image.BufferWidth} x {image.BufferHeight}
Image Stride: {image.Stride}

These lines indicate that Vuforia is successfully retrieving the camera image and provide details on image format, size, buffer dimensions, and stride. If these logs don’t appear, Vuforia isn’t able to retrieve the image.
I've tried updating the Vuforia SDK, creating a new project (3D and AR mobile), but the issue persists. Any suggestions for resolving this?

Hi, I'm not sure what error you're referring to. Running the sample code with the setup instructions from https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/working-camera-unity#access-the-camera-image works for me. The log you shared is just a Debug.Log. Could you elaborate on the error?

Hey, I think I know what the problem is. Yeah its not a error pre-say but whenever i try the code and try to register a pixelformat or leave it at default the configuration of vediobackground does not set to fix it I went through every format one by one until i foudn the one for my laptop device but i tired to build and run it on an android device the arcamera sence doesn't access the camera tried to remove the code it works fine on play mode and when built to android.
